# Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\View\Compilers\Compiler' not found in \vendor\compiled.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using a laravel 5.0 and now i am getting this error because of what no aritsan commands are working.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: try accepted php artisan optimize --force this command will re-generate a new compiled.php

Comment: I tried but then its giving `Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\View\Compilers\Compiler' not found in C:\wamp64\www\projectName\vendor\compiled.php on line 14258`

Comment: Do you mean `php artisan` command not working??

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
php artisan clear-compiled 
composer update
```

Comment: I did. but then its giving `Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\View\Compilers\Compiler' not found in C:\wamp64\www\projectName\vendor\compiled.php on line 14258` and no artisan command working now

Comment: Then it might be causing by any package you installed. Are you using `zizaco/entrust` or `kodeine acl` package? Could you display your `composer.json` file?